# How widgets like dijit Combobox gets data?

Tags: dojo

I am looking at dojo source but couldn't find How the `menu data` is being feeded to widgets like `ComboBox`, `FilteringSelect` etc ... . `ComboBox` inherits `ComboBoxMixin` which uses `PopupManager`

`DropDownMenu` inherits `dijit._MenuBase` But I cannot see where in `_MenuBase` it grabs the menu Items data and constructs the menu elements out of it.
There is `Menu.html`, 'MenuItem.html' in `templates/` But how these templates are being used that architecture is not clear yet.

Thats what I've understood from source but how the `menu data (may be data from store or hard coded data)` is feeded to these widgets is not yet understood. Can anybody explain a bit ?

Answer (score 1):

So in dojo 1.7.2, they have an _AutoCompleterMixin. _AutoCompleterMixin is mixed into the ComboBoxMixin

_AutoCompleterMixin has a startSearch function that gets invoked whenever user types in something into the combobox.

the startSearch function actually performs the fetch fromt he store. At lines 584 in _AutoCompleteMixin.js:

```
var resPromise = _this._fetchHandle = _this.store.query(query, options);
                Deferred.when(resPromise, function(res){
                    _this._fetchHandle = null;
                    res.total = resPromise.total;
                    _this._openResultList(res, query, options);
```

when the data is fetched, it invokes the _openResultList which passed the data to the createOptions function in _ComboBoxMixin.js

the createOptions function fills in the dropdown list DOM by using the items passed into it

Comment: btw I am keeping my old answer too in case someone else wants to learn how it is done in dojo 1.4.x

Answer (score 0):

Neel

Which version of dojo are you using?
In dojo 1.4, it behaves like this:

in dijit/form/ComboBox.js you will see a class called dijit.form._ComboBoxMenu 
in this class there is a method called _createOption in which you will see the DOM creation of the li element (menu is a typical ul li format)

from the code:

```
_createOption: function(/*Object*/ item, labelFunc){
        // summary:
        //      Creates an option to appear on the popup menu subclassed by
        //      `dijit.form.FilteringSelect`.

        var labelObject = labelFunc(item);
        var menuitem = dojo.doc.createElement("li");
        dijit.setWaiRole(menuitem, "option");
        if(labelObject.html){
            menuitem.innerHTML = labelObject.label;
        }else{
            menuitem.appendChild(
                dojo.doc.createTextNode(labelObject.label)
            );
```

The ComboBox class (ComboBoxMixin actually) invokes the _openResultList function which invokes the _createOption(s) on the popup widget. The good part is that the popup widget is a property of the ComboBox, so it is pluggable

It also has a _startSearch function in which it fetches the items from the store, sets a timer and when it expires, it shows the popup

```
    onComplete: dojo.hitch(this, "_openResultList"),
```

hope this helps

Vijay

Comment: I am using The Latest version 1.7.2